# WordPress ajax returns 404 bad request?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

The error is below

```html
POST http://localhost/...../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 400 (Bad Request)

send @ load-scripts.php?c=1…e,utils&ver=4.9.8:4 ajax @ load-scripts.php?c=1…e,utils&ver=4.9.8:4 (anonymous) @ my-ajax-handler.js?ver=0.1.0:24 i @ load-scripts.php?c=1…e,utils&ver=4.9.8:2 fireWith @ load-scripts.php?c=1…e,utils&ver=4.9.8:2 ready @ load-scripts.php?c=1…e,utils&ver=4.9.8:2
K @ load-scripts.php?c=1…e,utils&ver=4.9.8:2
```

```js
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url    : my_ajax_handler_var.ajaxurl,
                    
                    data   : {
                         action: 'rc_generate_pa'// "wp_ajax_*" action hook
                    },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json"
                    ,success:function(data) {
                         //This outputs the result of the ajax request
                        var pass = JSON.parse( data );
                        $('#p').val(data);
                        alert( JSON.parse(data));
                    },
                    error: function(errorThrown){
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                })
//                .done( function( response ) {
//                    var pass = response;
//                    $('#p').val(pass);
//                })
                .fail( function() {
                    console.log("failed");
                });
```

PHP code for enqueing script and handling request

```
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_st_page_scripts');
 function enqueue_st_page_scripts() {       
wp_register_script('my-ajax-handler', $plugin_url .'js/my-ajax-handler.js', array('jquery'), '0.1.0', true );
       wp_enqueue_script(array('my-ajax-handler'));
       $vars = array('ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'));
       wp_localize_script('my-ajax-handler', 'my_ajax_handler_var', $vars); 
   }

    add_action( 'wp_ajax_rc_generate_pa', 'rc_generate_p' );
        function rc_generate_p(){
            $pass = (string)wp_generate_password(8, true, false); 
            echo $pass;
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            $results = json_encode($pass);
            echo $results;
            exit;
        }
```

I have seen similar problems on this site and tried the solution,but no success. I am new to WordPress plugin development.

Comment: run code in comsole and tell me what result has been print code is : console.log(my_ajax_handler_var.ajaxurl);

Comment: It prints http://localhost/...../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php

Comment: All these dots make it a bad request, but I can't see where they come from. Is there maybe a config file where something like `$url="localhost/....."` is defined as an example url?

Comment: No. you misunderstood that. I put the ...... dots. I am sorry for confusing you. The original url it prints is  localhost/mysitename/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php I really appriciate your comments.

Comment: Visit `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=rc_generate_pa` and see if your `rc_generate_p()` gets called. If not, then it's normal for WordPress to throw the `400` error.

Comment: Yes I visited /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=rc_generate_pa
 and it outputs SnEI@ca# which is probably the json encoded results returned from rc_generate_p() I am just guessing

Comment: Actually, I think the AJAX request was successful; however, you're not sending a valid JSON response - or the `echo $pass;` part invalidates the response output. Try to comment it out or just remove it, then try again your AJAX call.

Comment: If "dataType" of your AJAX is json, you don't need "JSON.parse". your data is json

Comment: I tried the ways both of you suggested, but no success. I even set the $pass = "hello world", that didn't work either. Is it possible for any of you to replicate the problem and come up with the solution. By the way I am using WordPress version 4.9.8. Thank you guys for constant supports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Main Issue

The problem is in the `$.ajax()` call, where you should've *not* set the `contentType` to JSON:

```
$.ajax({
  url: my_ajax_handler_var.ajaxurl,
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  ...
});
```

because that way (from the PHP side), the action (i.e. `rc_generate_pa`) is not available in `$_REQUEST['action']` which WordPress uses to determine the AJAX action being called, and when the action is not known, WordPress throws the `400 Bad Request` error.

So to fix the error, just remove the `contentType` property: (or use something other than the JSON type)

```
$.ajax({
  url: my_ajax_handler_var.ajaxurl,
  // Don't set contentType
  ...
});
```

### Second Issue

In your `$.ajax()`'s `success` callback, don't use the `JSON.parse( data )`; and here's why:

1. When `dataType` is `json`, jQuery will automatically parse the response output into a JSON object — or it could also be a *string*; see point #2 below.
2. In the (PHP) `rc_generate_p()` function, the `$pass` is neither an `array` nor `object`/`class`; hence in the `$.ajax()`'s `success` callback, the `data` is actually an *invalid JSON string* and `JSON.parse( data )` will throw a JavaScript syntax error.

So your `$.ajax()`'s `success` could be rewritten into:

```
success: function(data){
  $('#p').val(data);
  console.log(typeof data); // test
})
```

### Third Issue

In your `rc_generate_p()` function, remove the `echo $pass;`, or you'll get a JavaScript syntax error — your AJAX call is expecting a JSON response, and yet that `echo` part invalidates the JSON.

*I know you probably added that to debug the `400` error; but I thought I should just remind you about removing it.. :)*

And you might want to consider using [`wp_send_json()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_send_json/) like so, where you don't need to call `exit`, `die`, or [`wp_die()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_die/):

```
function rc_generate_p() {
  $pass = wp_generate_password( 8 );
  wp_send_json( $pass );
}
```

Comment: Thank you all to save my project, particularly Sally CJ for being so quick to resolve the issue. I have been stuck on this for days. Many thanks again.

Comment: I wanted to give you vote up, but I don't have enough reputations (at least 15) to do so. Hopefully sometime in the future.

Comment: You're very welcome, I'm glad I could help you. And it's alright about the vote up. :) Cheers!